# Unity3D NavMesh: shortest path to an area

Tags: unity-game-engine, path-finding, navmesh

Consider the following situation.

There is a predefined area inside NavMesh that AI agent must reach. For convenience - it is circular area.

[image]

To find **the closest point** of the area is pretty straightforward task. No, I need to find **the shortest path** to an area.

In the picture example the closest point obviously requires from an agent to travel further than optimal distance is.

So, how to calculate desired destination point in such situation?

Do I have to implement a [wave propagation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lee_algorithm) algorithm myself? Use the **A*** instead of built-in NavMesh? Are there any simple solutions involving Unity3D tools?

**Note**: desired area is just an abstraction defined by (Vector3) position and (float) radius, not an actual object in game scene.

Comment: Maybe some heuristic:
1. Divide your circle into for example 8 parts like a pizza
2. Calculate the centre point of the circle edge of each part.
3. Calculate 8 paths to these points and choose the shortest.
You can try to combine `NavMesh.CalculatePath` and `NavMeshPathStatus` to calculate the path distance.
The more parts the more accurate the result.

Comment: @PandaStrong, It is definitely an option, however, I'm concerned about performance of this solution. Calculating 8 paths at once looks not very friendly performance-wise. And if I'd need to improve accuracy - paths count could increase substantially.